# necesito crear un temporizador en wpf que cada cierto minutos me haga un guardado automatico

Tags: c#, wpf

Estoy creando un formulario en wpf en el cual hace la creación de un contrato  en el cual  mediante `StreamWrite` hice que  guarde lo ultimo ingresado y lo recupere, pero necesito ademas crear un temporizador que cada cierto tiempo haga un guardado automático

[image: en esa parte de la imagen esta donde se guardan los datos ingresados]

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a stackoverflow, te recomiendo que leas [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que puedas formular mejor tus preguntas. Si es posible, puedes poner el código y no solo la foto.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Respondiendo a tu duda, puedes usar simplemente un `DispatcherTimer`